# Warning: Illegal string offset PHP Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm trying to fetch data from mysql database using this code :

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'nicu');
    mysqli_query($con, "set NAMES utf8");
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from user");
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) :
        $rows = $rows["nicuAddress"];
        $address = $rows["nicuEmail"];
        echo "$rows<br>$address";
    endwhile;
```

but every time i run this code i get this warning :`Warning: Illegal string offset`

what changes do i have to do to fix this ?

Comment: Not sure if the cause of your error, but you are overwriting `$rows` on the first line of the loop. That looks wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara yep , i didn't notice that thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to reaches a part of the array that was overwritten. After running `$rows = $rows["nicuAddress"]` you cannot access `$address = $rows["nicuEmail"]` as an array.

**Solution**

```
$address = $rows["nicuAddress"]; // <-- Change to address
$email = $rows["nicuEmail"]; // <-- Change to email
echo "$address<br>$email";
```